# Is using two states in React an anti-pattern when one state can entirely determine the other state?

Tags: reactjs

In the project, let's say if there are 6 steps for the user to go through, and if in step 3, the user chooses Option B instead of Option A, then step 4 and step 5 would go away.

Therefore, I can use

```
  const [isOptionBChosen, setIsOptionBChosen] = useState(false);
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState(['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step4', 'step5', 'step6']);
```

Note that `steps` will be passed to sub-components, to render the right content in those components depending on what `steps` is.

and in step3 where the user chooses Option A or B in a select field, I can use something like:

```
  onChange={v => {
                   setSteps(
                     v === "optionA" ? 
                            ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step4', 'step5', 'step6'] : 
                            ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step6']
                   );
                   setIsOptionBChosen(v === "optionB");
           }}
```

However, `steps` really can be determined by `isOptionBChosen`, so the code could use

```
  const steps = isOptionBChosen ? 
                  ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step6'] :
                  ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step4', 'step5', 'step6'];
```

and so `steps` will NOT be a separate state.  In this example, `steps` is simple, but in some other situations, say, `steps` can be "computed", meaning it can be generated using `.map()` or `.filter()`.

Alternatively, we can still use two states like before, but use:

```
  useEffect(() => {
                    setSteps(
                      isOptionBChosen ? 
                            ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step6'] : 
                            ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step4', 'step5', 'step6']
                   );
  }, [isOptionBChosen]);
```

Is using two states an anti-pattern (meaning not recommended) in React, when one state can totally determine another?

Answer (score 1):

The *steps* variable is what we call a derived state.

And it's anti pattern. Why?

Because it will trigger more re-renders than necessary:

- `setIsOptionBChosen` will trigger a re-render
- `setSteps` will trigger a re-render

Well, actually I am not saying everything:

- before v17, it would only trigger one re-render if those were called from the React Event handlers (`onChange` is fine), but two from timeouts, intervals, effects, etc.
- from v18, event batching applies to more cases.

Comment: yes, I noticed a `setFoo()` and `setBar()` both ran but may cause only one re-render

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it makes no sense to track which option the user has chosen, only for you to then also

1. make another state change to update the steps based on the chosen option
2. OR perform a side effect of the option change, which updates the steps

What you could do, is simply have one state, which holds the information about which steps the user will have displayed. You could reason that the options dropdown is the mechanism with which the user is changing the steps, so there is no need to keep track of that particular piece of information, since it is only used to switch between steps display.

Answer (score 0):

I was going more by intuition, and now I understand it better. A simple rule of thumb is:

1. Determine the minimum number of states that you need, and make them states (as by using `useState()`)
2. For other values that can be determined by this set of minimum states, let them be derived, (and we can view them as "derived values"),  by using directly assignment:

```
const v = state1 === "someValue" ? ["a", "b"] : ["a", "c", "d"];
```

or if the computation can be expensive, such as if it involves a sort or filtering, then use the `useMemo()` hook to do it, so that it doesn't need to go through the lengthy process of getting the results every time, but only if any of the dependencies changes.

One other pattern is that, when the user changes the dropbox or option, directly manipulate the state so that it becomes the new state, so that no derived value is needed.  For example, if the `data` can be sorted by a field, we may consider directly sorting the data and put it into the new state, instead of deriving a `sortedData`.

In any event, try not to use `useEffect()` to set the new state. That's because the function in `useEffect()` is run after one re-rendering, and if you change any state in there, then it will cause yet another re-rendering, making it less efficient. For more details: see https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect